# Importing divs in a .html page

Tags: html

I think I made a mistake long ago of making .html extensions for my web pages in one site.

Now I want to do things like import divs, and make things modular, but I have a feeling it is not possible.

In PHP I could do something like

```
<?php
include("divs/footer.php");
?>
```

But how could I import a div in a page with a .html extension? Or does the .html extension not matter?

Thanks!

Comment: What server environment? Apache? IIS? Do you need the includes to be parsed as PHP, or are they just static html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extension does not matter.

Comment: You could modify your .htaccess file by adding the following line: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`. The downside is that your server will now interpret all .html files as .php files.

Comment: If you only need to include php on one html page, it's better to add this to your .htaccess file: `<Files yourpage.html>AddType application/x-httpd-php .html</Files>`

Comment: When I first read your question, I misinterpreted what you were asking. I thought you were asking if you could include a file with an html extension, not use php include in an html file. My apologies for any confusion.

Comment: @Actually the php thing was just an example.  I need to simply include an html div, which I am still not sure how :)

Comment: You can use php include in your html file, as long as you modify your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few choices. You could tell your server to execute `.html` files with the PHP interpreter, but that might be kind of confusing for someone in the future. I think it would be better to rename your pages to .php and update all links on your site. Then set up a redirect from the `*.html` to `*.php` with HTTP 301 so that any old bookmarks or links still work.

Another option you have is to use mod_rewrite to rewrite all your urls from `/pagename.html` to `/index.php?page=pagename`. Then you could have `index.php` just do something like:

```
<?php

if(strpos($_GET['page'], '../') !== false)
    die; // Do not allow traversing up the directory tree

require dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$_GET['page'];

?>
```

You may want to do more checking to make sure the file is valid, but that code will only require files below the web root so it should be safe to use.